# Order of the differential equation $y''' + cos(y') = xy$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What will the **order** and **degree** of the following differential equation be?
$$y''' + cos(y') = xy$$

My instructor said **order** will be 3, **degree** will be 1. But I think that we cannot define order, degree here, because a differential coefficient is inside domain of a function!

My teacher said that highest order differential coefficient must be outside any function for defining order or degree. Is it true? My book doesn't specify this. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "a differential coefficient is inside domain of a function"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My teacher said that highest order differential coefficient must be
>   outside any function for defining order or degree. Is it true?

In this case, the comment is irrelevant, since the highest order derivative, a third derivative, is outside any function. The order is therefore 3.

As a general statement, though I'm not persuaded that your teacher is correct. You could, allowing for fiddling around with domains of definition, re-write the ODE as
$$
\cos^{-1}({y'''}) + y' = \cos^{-1}{(xy)}.
$$
It would be bizarre for one's definition of order to require these two, equivalent ODEs to have different orders.

Comment: Oh yes. Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The order is defined and it's $3$ because this is the  highest order derivative of the dependent variable, but the degree can be defined only if the  differential equation is a polynomial equation in derivatives, so, in this case, the degree is not defined.